# XCode8 TextureAtlas compiler did not produce

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, texture-atlas, sktextureatlas

I was adding new particle.sks file into my Swift 3.0 project in XCode8. I created the partile-file with the XCode editor. I have many particles already (done in XCode7). All of sudden my app won't compile because of:

```
TextureAtlas compiler did not produce "/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-oaswssggehsvaiboevihuqcwxbjq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.app/Particle Sprite Atlas.atlasc"
```

I don't understand what's going wrong. I have deleted the derived data abd cleaned the product. Nothing seems to work. Does this error description mean more to you? Could you assist how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

This is an odd error that I got recently as well. If @user594883's answer seems a bit cryptic. Here is what he means:

Click on your .xcassets file

[image]

Then in the left hand side of the assets navigator delete `Particle Sprite Atlas`

[image]

Comment: love the screenshot. appreciate the beautifully drawn arrow lol ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error that was also caused by the inability to compile the .atlas file. However, deleting the file did not solve the problem. Upon inspection I saw that the spaces in the file were replaced with the URL encoding of %20, therefore, the directory was named: 'Particle%20Sprite%20Atlas' on the hard disk. Deleting the file resulted in an empty particle emitter view.

Once I renamed the file to not contain any spaces the compilation and runtime issues were solved.

Hope this helps.

Ron

Answer (score 1):

Turns out XCode had generated a texture Atlas that I hadn't noticed. Simply deleting this fixed the error.